# Angular 2: check radio button on div click

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i want to check radio button, get value and add class 'selected' to sectionBlock when user clicks on div

please help not getting how to do this in angular 2

```js
selectPlant(){
    console.log('');
  }
```

```html
<div class="SectionContent">
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="AEP" /><span>AEP</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="ELP" /><span>ELP</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="HCL" /><span>HCL</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="HCM" /><span>HCM</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="HDA" /><span>HDA</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="HMA" /><span>HMA</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="HMI" /><span>HMI</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="HSC" /><span>HSC</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="MAP" /><span>MAP</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="MMP" /><span>MMP</span></div>
    <div class="sectionBlock" (click)="selectPlant($event)"><input type="radio" class="plant" name="plant" value="PMC" /><span>PMC</span></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use directive ngClass when the radio is selected, you have something variable selectedInput

example with one

```
div [ngClass]="{'sectionBlock': selectedInput}" (click)="selectPlant('AEP')">
```

Comment: if the radio is selected this directive add the class to div tag